# how to display the result after the submit php form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

how to display the result after submit the form

i want a display result after submit the form for print

example 1st im filling the form submit the result after the submit i want a screen to display same result
http://www.tizag.com/phpT/examples/formexample.php

how can i do this 
please help me to fix this issue.

php form code

```
<?php
     function renderForm($grn, $name, $rollno, $class, $fees, $date, $reference, $error)
     {
     ?>
     <?php 
     if ($error != '')
     {
     echo '<div style="padding:4px; border:1px solid red; color:red;">'.$error.'</div>';
     }
     ?> 
     <form action="" method="post">
     <div>
       <p><span class="style9"><strong>G.R.N No:</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
         <input name="grn" type="text" id="grn" value="<?php echo $grn; ?>" size="50" />
       </p>
       <p><span class="style9"><strong>Name:</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
         <input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" size="50" />
       </p>

       <p><span class="style9"><strong>Roll No :</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
         <input name="rollno" type="text" id="rollno" value="<?php echo $rollno; ?>" size="50" />
       </p>
       <p><span class="style9"><strong>Class:</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
         <input name="class" type="text" id="class" value="<?php echo $class; ?>" size="50" />
       </p>
        <p><span class="style9"><strong>Fees Date  :</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
          <input id="fullDate"  name="date" type="text" value="<?php echo $date; ?>" size="50" />
       </p>
        <p><span class="style9"><strong>Fees :</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
          <input name="fees" type="text" value="<?php echo $fees; ?>" size="50" />
       </p>
        <span class="style9"><strong>Reference</strong></span><strong> *</strong>
        <input name="reference" type="text" value="<?php echo $reference; ?>" size="50">
        <br/>
       <p class="style1">* required</p>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
     </div>
     </form> 
     <?php 
     }
     include('connect-db.php');

     if (isset($_POST['submit']))
     { 
     // get form data, making sure it is valid
     $grn = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['grn']));
     $name = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
     $rollno = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['rollno']));
     $class = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['class']));
     $fees = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['fees']));
     $date = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['date']));
     $reference = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['reference']));


     // check to make sure both fields are entered
     if ($grn == '' || $name == '' || $rollno == '')
     {
     // generate error message
     $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';

     // if either field is blank, display the form again
     renderForm($grn, $name, $rollno, $class, $fees, $date, $reference, $error);
     }
     else
     {
     // save the data to the database
      mysql_query("INSERT fees SET grn='$grn', name='$name', rollno='$rollno', class='$class', fees='$fees', date='$date', reference='$reference'")
     or die(mysql_error()); 
     echo "<center>KeyWord Submitted!</center>";
     // once saved, redirect back to the view page

     }
     }
     else
     // if the form hasn't been submitted, display the form
     {
     renderForm('','','','','','','','');
     }

    ?>
```

Comment: simple redirect the form after submit, to page where you need to display results, save data in db, get data from db and display.

Comment: By Same Result you mean the data you submitted in the html form?

Comment: how can i redirect the last result

Comment: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/examples/formexample.php example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite shure what you are asking.

do you need help displaying the submited form data? or more spesific display for print?

to display it you would just need to make a `html` page that displays it.
like:

```
echo '<table><tr>';
  echo '<td>';
    echo '<Strong>Name:</strong><br/>';
    echo $name;
  echo '</td>';
echo '</tr></table>';
```

To display just the result and not the form, when you post to the same page you need to encapsulate the for code with an if statement.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  //code for the php form
}else {
  //code to display form
}
```

Comment: yes u are right but how can i show the result in new window for print

Comment: If you whant to use a seperate php file to render the results. you need to change the post action
   <form action="print.php" method="post">

otherwise just echo the results in the else statement.

Comment: ok i understand and i create print.php page the same code working on print.php page? echo '<table><tr>';
  echo '<td>';
    echo '<Strong>Name:</strong

Comment: you would need to move most of your php code to the "print.php" page. ore make a copy. You accsess the data the same way you did in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use a new page for the "action" part in the form. On that new page, simply echo the $_POST of values you want to display. If you plan on making some sort of page so that people can check their entries, you could store these $_POST-data in sessions.

Answer (score 0):

*Simply call function on the bottom to disply posted values :*

```
    function showFormValues()
         {
         ?>


         <div>
           <p><span class="style9"><strong>G.R.N No:</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
              <?php echo $_POST['grn']; ?>
           </p>
           <p><span class="style9"><strong>Name:</strong></span><strong>  *</strong>
              <?php echo $_POST['name'];
           </p>
and so on.
    .
    .
    .
    .
         </div>

         <?php 
         }
?>
```